# Compare multiple array values and return keys of duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

**SOLUTION**

```
$hours = array(
    'Mo' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '20:00'),
    'Tu' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
    'We' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '20:00'),
    'Th' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
    'Fr' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
    'Sa' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '11:00', 'to' => '16:00'),
    'Su' => array('false' => true, 'from' => '11:00', 'to' => '16:00')
);

$res = [];
foreach($hours as $k=>$v) {
    if($v['open']){
        $t = $v['from'] . ' - ' . $v['to'];
        if (! isset($res[$t]))  $ret[$t] = [];
        $res[$t][] = $k;
    }
}
$final = [];
foreach($res as $k=>$v) {
  $final[] = implode(', ', $v) . ' ' . $k;
}
echo implode(' ', $final);
```

**Edited to include comments**

Trying to find a solution to compare multiple values in a multidimensional array and return matching array keys in groups.

Example array:

```
$hours = array(
'Mo' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '20:00'),
'Tu' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
'We' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '20:00'),
'Th' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
'Fr' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
'Sa' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '11:00', 'to' => '18:00'),
'Su' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '11:00', 'to' => '18:00')
);
```

So, the above example would result in **Mo & We** being grouped together, **Tu, Th, Fr** grouped together, and **Sa & Su** grouped together. 
My intention is to use the results to condense the hours for ld+jason schema. The desired end result would be a string that looks like this: `Mo, We 10:00 - 20:00 Tu, Th, Fr 10:00 - 18:00 Sa, Su 11:00 - 16:00` Best way to achieve this?

I looked at array intersect, but that doesn't seem to be what i want. (or at least i cant wrap my head around how to get from the multidimensional array i shared to the result i need using it. this is to compare two arrays not multiple levels of a multidimensional array.

Comment: you can add field 'group' to each item in array

Comment: How will you use the result array?  - that setups array structure   ?

Comment: My intention is to use the results to condense the hours for ld+jason schema. The desired end result would be a string that looks like this: Mo, We 10:00 - 08:00 Tu, Th, Fr 10:00 - 06:00 Sa, Su 11:00 - 04:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipp array and gather days with the same timetable

```
$res = [];
foreach($hours as $k=>$v) {
  $t = $v['from'] . ' - ' . $v['to'];
  if (! isset($res[$t]))  $ret[$t] = [];
  $res[$t][] = $k;
}

foreach($res as $k=>$v) {
  echo implode(', ', $v) . ' ' . $k ."\n";
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/927601)

Comment: oh this looks like a winner.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use **array_intersect** function .

```
    <?php 
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow")‌​; 
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue"); 
$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2); print_r($result); 
?>
```

output

```
Array ( [a] => red [b] => green [c] => blue )
```

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer with the comments you posted. It's way better than adding new comments.

Comment: I looked at array intersect, but that doesn't seem to be what i want. (or at least i cant wrap my head around how to get from the multidimensional array i shared to the result i need using it. this is to compare two arrays not multiple levels of a multidimensional array.

Comment: Doing a custom comparison, you'll need to use array_uintersect() php.net/array_uintersect, which uses a user-defined comparison function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better solution, but this can give you a good result.

```
$hours = array(
    'Mo' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '08:00'),
    'Tu' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '06:00'),
    'We' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '08:00'),
    'Th' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '06:00'),
    'Fr' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '10:00', 'to' => '06:00'),
    'Sa' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '11:00', 'to' => '04:00'),
    'Su' => array('open' => true, 'from' => '11:00', 'to' => '04:00')
);

$newHours = [];
foreach ($hours as $day => $hour){
    $index = array_search($hour, $newHours);
    if ( $index == false ){
        $newHours[$day] = $hour;
    }else{
        unset($newHours[$index]);
        $newHours[$index . ',' . $day] = $hour; 
    }
}

print_r($newHours);
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [Mo,We] => Array
        (
            [open] => 1
            [from] => 10:00
            [to] => 08:00
        )

    [Tu,Th,Fr] => Array
        (
            [open] => 1
            [from] => 10:00
            [to] => 06:00
        )

    [Sa,Su] => Array
        (
            [open] => 1
            [from] => 11:00
            [to] => 04:00
        )

)
```

Comment: i think this is enough to get me where i want to go. testing now and i will report back! thanks!